# Access 2007 Conditional Formating on Datasheet View takes several seconds to load

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is my second question here, so I hope I ask the right way this time.

*Background: I'm designing an Access Database to do some calculations. I got that part. My problem is the visual design. I hate forms. I'm an Excel man and I like to work on Raw data normally, so I suck designing forms. This questions is 100% to improve performance about a conditional formating rule.*

I applied a simple conditiona rule in a form (style is datasheet View) where if the value of a Field is True, then it colours ALL the fields of the record. The rule works perfect. It does exactly what I want.

> **PROBLEM:** When the list contains several records, it takes some time for Access to colour all rows according to my Conditional
>   Formating rule. We are talking about 5 or even 10 seconds.

Some Images:

[image]

But with more records...

[image]

And I have to wait around 5-10 seconds untill all of them are colored, and If i scroll down to see more of the list, some of them are not colored and I have to wait again some seconds.
[image]

> **QUESTION:** ¿Is there any way I can delay the load until the Conditional Formating is applied to all records? ¿Or a way to do it
>   faster?

WHAT I HAVE TRIED UNTIL KNOW:

I have tried playing with `Application.Echo` and also `Repaint`. I don't know anything else to try. Tried both optionsin different events of the form and nothing helped.

I do not post any code or data because is not really about bad coding or data manage. Is just if anybody knows something that can accelerate this procces or delay the load of this form until all Conditional Formating has been applied.

**P.S:** There are no macros running in background when user checks this form, so is not a problem of performance of computer or other macros interfering. Also, this database must be done in Access 2007, no other option is available for final user.

Thanks for anyone that can provide a solution. I hope this time I asked the right way.

**ANSWERING COMMENTS:** Nope, all data is a query from tables inside same database. No custom functions in the query. Not a single calculation, it just takes data stored in tables. Is't located in local drive. We are talking about 635 records right now, but it will have more records in the future. And yes, I have activated "Compact & Repair". Database size is actually around 5 Megabytes.

Comment: Are there references to external files or data sources?  Custom functions? Is this stored on the local C: or on a network? How many records are we talking about?  Do you "Compact & Repair" and reboot regularly?

Comment: Nope, all data is a query from tables inside same database. No custom functions in the query. Not a single calculation, it just takes data stored in tables. Is't located in local drive. We are talking about 635 records right now, but it will have more records in the future. And yes, I have activated "Compact & Repair". Database size is actually around 5 Megabytes.

Comment: how many fields?  5mb seems like a lot for only 600 records

Comment: Because i got a lot of tables and queries, but this form just 1 query, and 13 fields.

Comment: Except that FC can be dead-slow, perhaps your expression used is "less than optimal"?

Comment: My expression is just "[FieldName]=True", but indeed it must check all records to see if that Field is true or not. Could that be that FC is dead-slow even with a simple expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Access to process all records:

```
Do Until Me.Recordset.EOF
   Me.Recordset.MoveNext
Loop
Me.Recordset.MoveFirst
```

A large difference is that normally, conditional formatting is applied without locking the application, but this will lock the application.

Comment: This worked perfectly!. I combined your solution with `Me.Painting=False` and then `Me.Painting=True` at the end and performance increased really nice. I had trie before `Me.Painting` but I did not combine it with your solution. This worked awesome. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked. I hadn't included the `Me.Painting` code because I was unsure if that would affect conditional formatting. You can, of course, limit the processing to the first 30 or so records (by using a counter, and `Do Until Me.Recordset.EOF Or i=30`), to only force processing of the first screen, and limit the time the application is locked.

Comment: I added it because without that, the screen "flickers" while you can see how it checks all records. With `Me.Painting=False` then user don't see anything until all process is done. So I'm really happy with this solution. I had no idea that moving between records with VBA would activate CF, but I learned something new today. Million Thanks!.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth If i dont use formatting in VBA, but directly in the gui - Then where do I put that Do Loop?

Comment: @EmilOlsen You don't. If you don't use a form, you have very little control over anything that happens. The easy solution is: use a form.

Comment: I do use a form. But i use the built in condition formatting. (Right clicking on the title -> conditional formatting)

Comment: Ah, then you can put this code in the `Form_Load` event to execute it on load